# c# save tcpclients which are connected to server

Tags: c#, networking, tcpclient

I am new to c# and I am building server / client application.
I have created both the server and the client successfully , but when any client connects to the server... I need to save that client because the server is supposed to send them a message after 10 minutes .

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TcpListener myList;

    myList = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8001);

    while (true)

    {
        TcpClient client = myList.AcceptTcpClient();

        MessageBox.Show("Connection accepted from " + client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now , my problem is how to save "client" id or anything about this client which is connected, to send message after 10 minutes from server to this client.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I would look at [WCF duplex nettcpbinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF) or [Signal R](http://signalr.net/) if you can use HTTP instead of TCP.

Answer (score 3):

Form onLoad is rather bad place to accept clients. Instead use ,for example, Background Worker. Also you might want to avoid using while(true) without any way to break the loop.

Object storage must be outside of method (event handler) to preserve connections from evil Garbage Collector. There are many ways to store object, it might be array (bothersome) or some collection, which although heavier to compute are pleasant to use. You can even use Concurent collections which will take care of thread synchronization on their own.

```
Dictionary<string,TcpClient> clientDict;
List<TcpClient> clientList;
...
void acceptClients()
{

    TcpListener myList;

    myList = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8001);

    while (true)

    {
        TcpClient client = myList.AcceptTcpClient();
        clientDict.Add("client nickname, id etc.",client);
        clientList.Add(client);

        MessageBox.Show("Connection accepted from " + client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
        if (clientList.count>=8 || clientDict.count>=8)
        {
            break; // I want to break freeeeee!!!!
        }
    }
}
...
void sendToClient(string nick)
{
    if (clientDict.ContainsKey(nick))
    {
        TcpClient client = clientDict[nick];
        //and use selected client.
    }

}
void broadcast()
{
    foreach(TcpClient client in clientList) //clientList can be replaced with clientDict.Values
    {
        //and use selected client.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , but ... if you can save the client in 'clientDict' , how you select the client and how do you send message to this selected client ?

Comment: I updated response with examples of usage. For further lecture check MSDN articles about [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) and [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) (or Generic Collections as whole).

Answer (score 1):

you would have to store the TCPClient in some list/dictionary. Regarding identifying connections you can use IP/Port in the TCPClient to differentiate between different connections.

Below is one such article i have posted to create a multi-threaded TCP chat application. it might be helpful.

http://shoaibsheikh.blogspot.com/2012/05/multi-threaded-tcp-socket-chat-server.html

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way is to keep the connection open. Because many clients connect from behind [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) devices (corporate access points, home routers etc) is not possible to ask the client for a 'call back' address (IP:port).

What that mean in C# code, you need a reference to the `client` object you created in `AcceptTcpClient`. When you want to send something, you must retrieve this object and [`Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) something into the client's stream (obtained via [`client.GetStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). How exactly this is accomplished, it depends entirely on your code. A [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) perhaps? *Do* expect the connection to had closed by then for various reasons, even if [`KeepAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is set.

Note that having a large number of accepted connections is not feasible (for many reasons).